# Shiny reactive as ggplot2 series name and legend label?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I want to use a Shiny input as a name in my shiny plot.

Here is my code:

```
ggplot() + 
    ...
    geom_point(data=data.frame(), aes(x=x, y=y, color=paste(input$name)),
      size = 3) + 
    scale_color_manual(values=c("df1"="blue", "df2"="blue",
      paste(input$name)="red"))
```

It doesn't recognize `paste(input$name)` as a string. Here is the error message:

```
1512:     scale_color_manual(values=c("df1"="blue", "df2"="blue",
1513:       paste(input$name)=
                             ^
```

Anyone know how to properly structure this?

Comment: Why would I do that? I provided both tags that are not working properly, all the other geoms are working fine. The issue is the ggplot2 functions don't recognize `paste(input$name)` as functions that call a string within the function. I'm asking if anyone has figured out how to get around that. I didn't post all 20 lines of the plot because I didn't want to have to go through and censor 20 lines containing proprietary information in my code.

Answer (score 1):

You can't intermix strings and symbols and expressions like you are doing. If you want to use a string in an `aes()` mapping, use `aes_` or `aes_string` (no need for `paste`)

```
aes_string(x="x", y="y", color=input$name)
```

And you can't put an expression on the left of `=` in a named vector. Use something like `setNames()` instead.

```
values = setNames(c("blue", "blue", "red"), c("df1", "df2", input$name))
```

As requested above, it would be easier in the future if you include a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) so that possible solutions can be properly tested. This isn't at all Shiny related. This is just how `ggplot` and R work.